# SSL issue WSO2 SP 4.4

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm getting a ssl handshake error on wso2 SP 4.4 when trying to consume an external api (elastic search). I already imported the certificate and chains into client-truststore.jks but the error persists. I turned off host checking on the start command but also did not resolve.

Could someone give me a hint?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show us the exact error, copy and paste it into your answer.

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1521)

Comment: Here is the siddhi app:

Comment: Here is the siddhi app:@App:name('FlowManagement')
define trigger FiveMinTrig at every 10 sec;
@sink(type = 'http-request', publisher.url ='https://myurl',basic.auth.username ='*', basic.auth.password = '*',method = 'POST',"sslVerificationDisabled:'true'",sink.id = "test",
 @map(type = 'json'))
define stream ReqStream (Id string);
@source(type = 'http-response', sink.id = 'test',http.status.code='200',@map(type = 'json', @attributes(Id = 'trp:Id')))
 @sink(type = 'log')
 define stream RespStream (Id string);
from FiveMinTrig select "test" as Id insert into ReqStream;

Answer (score 0):

Does your endpoint have mutual SSL? In this case, the endpoint can additionally send a certificate to request client and expect it to verify